# Download Entity framework for .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-3.5

Which version of the **Entity Framework** (EF) I could use in **.NET 3.5** and where I could download this older version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For .Net 3.5 you can use EF v1.

Did you try to download Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22 
It should include The first version of Entity Framework (EFv1) as stated on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework.

Comment: Thx for advise, Have You any link for direct download EFv1 ?

Comment: afaik the SP1 download (the first link) includes the EF