# This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework. I have installed .net framework 3.5 with sp 1. I am using vs 2008.

But, I am getting this below error:

> Error 1   Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies.
>   This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: Well which version of the entity framework are you trying to use?

Comment: VS2008 (and .net 3.5) is two versions ago. Since adding Entity framework is a pretty big change, could you update the whole project to a more recent environment?

Comment: I am using Entity Framewrok 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using EF4.x or EF 5.x. The first version targets `.Net 4.0` and the second one targets `.Net 4.5`. If you need to use `.Net 3.5` you should use an early version of the EF library.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am using entity framework 4.0. But how I can you early version of the EF library. Can you help me.

Comment: I advise you to go with the latest version of EF and .NET. but if you have a requirement forcing the application to run on .NET 3.5, see the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330682/download-entity-framework-for-net-3-5

Comment: Yes I got it. I cannot use code first Entity Mode with VS- 2008. For code first model we need entity framework 4.x or above.
Thanks for answer. So I can use only "Database First model" with entity framework 3.5.